# Set Windows Server 2012 default screen resolution (VM Ware)

Tags: vmware, resolution, windows-server-2012, jenkins

I need to set (default) screen resolution to Win Server 2012 hosted in VMWare vcentrum
5.5.0. It is a dedicated server for running automatic GUI tests for Windows applications by Jenkins. When connected from Jenkins, it has the screen resolution of 1024x768. I need higher, at least 1024px height.

What i tried so far:

**Run setres.exe from Jenkins**

```
c:\windows\system32\setres.exe -w 1280 -h 1024
```

result: The settings passed in could not be applied to the graphics device.

**Add the following lines to the vmx file**

```
svga.autodetect = "FALSE" 
svga.vramSize = "20971520" 
svga.maxWidth = "1920" 
svga.maxHeight = "1080"
```

result: setres.exe -i still returns 1024x768

**Use Win API functions: *ChangeDisplaySettings*, *EnumDisplaySettings***

I wrote a C# utility which worked correctly on WS2003 (run from Jenkins) & Win7 (run locally), but on WS2012 run from Jenkins *EnumDisplaySettings* returns:

```
Supported Modes:
1024 by 768, 32 bit, 60 hertz
1280 by 1024, 32 bit, 60 hertz
1920 by 1080, 32 bit, 60 hertz
...shortened
```

However *ChangeDisplaySettings* returns

```
-1  : dislplay change failed
```

**Alter registry:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{A8405CA4-B9D8-4123-B809-D912D3B666DC}\0000
```

[image]

result: none and after Jenkins connects, it sets the keys VidPNSource0Width & Height back to 1024x768

Any ideas?

Edit:
VM hardware settings
[image]

Comment: Is there any Video card connected?. What cable you are using VGA/HDMI/DVI?.

Comment: No, its a virtual machine. No cables.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. I misread VMWare vcentrum.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure VMTools is installed on the virtual machine
- Shut down the virtual machine
- Go to Edit Settings for the machine
- Select the video card
- Increase the Total video memory to about 64 MB

That should provide you with a wide array of possible resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Within the VM client settings just go to graphic cards adapter, "List all modes", choose a mode, click OK and click OK again.

Comment: I have no such settings there. Please see the screenshot at the bottom of the question.

Comment: ahh right sorry, well then judging by the software I would suggest this page http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1820753/vmware-virtual-machine-incorrect-display-resolution.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [MultiRes](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/multires.shtm) - maybe it would succeed where setres failed.